# Confusion about notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Is $Z_{11}$ same as $\frac{Z}{11Z}$. I have been said in class that latter contains equivalence classes, but in assignment i have seen $Z_{11}$. Can someone clarify difference between two ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the notations $\mathbb Z_{11}$ and $\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z$ are commonly used for the ring of integers modulo $11$.

The notation $\frac{\mathbb Z}{11\mathbb Z}$ is less common; quotients of algebraic structures are almost always written with a slash, not with a fraction bar.

With the notation $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$ the elements of the ring are invariably constructed as equivalence classes (because that's what the quotient notation *means*). Authors who write $\mathbb Z_{11}$ may either have defined the ring in the same way, or *ad hoc* as $\{0,1,\ldots,10\}$ with special arithmetic operations, as Yoyostein describes.

Other notations for this include $\mathbb Z/(11)$, $\mathbb Z/\langle 11 \rangle$, or $\mathbb F_{11}$ if you want to emphasize that it's a *field* (every nonzero element has an inverse modulo $11$).

---

There's a *different* possible meaning of $\mathbb Z_{11}$, namely the ring of [11-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). Some people prefer the longer notation for the ring of integers modulo $11$ in order to avoid confusion with this.

Comment: i don't know anything about rings

Comment: @Gathdi: A [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) is just a set with an "addition" and a "multiplication" operation that satisfy (many of) the same laws as addition and multiplication on integers.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, they are different as sets.

$\mathbb{Z}_{11}=\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 9, 10\}$

Each element is a number. Addition is done modulo 11.

$\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}=\{0+11\mathbb{Z}, 1+11\mathbb{Z}, \dots, 10+11\mathbb{Z}\}$

Each element is a coset (which is an equivalence class like what you said).

However, as groups they are isomorphic.

Other notations you may see are $\mathbb{Z}/11$, or $C_{11}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I forgot where exactly I first saw it. But here is one site with this notation (https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=3Yd01mY_qL8C&pg=PA397&lpg=PA397&dq=Z/2+algebraic+topology&source=bl&ots=IaSgmchvYT&sig=Oc-mTwliAmPq4ndrNyu9aKcaImM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNraK0sa_OAhUHuI8KHRc7Da8Q6AEIODAH#v=onepage&q=Z%2F2%20algebraic%20topology&f=false). Algebraic Topologists seem to be fond of writing this shortcut.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the notation $\,\Bbb Z_{11}\,$ is not used for the construction using equivalence classes. But this is not true. There is no unique correspondence between the common notations and constructions.

Comment: In my experience $C_{11}$ is used for a cyclic group of order $11$. This is not quite the same, as a priori there then is no natural ring structure and introducing one amounts to choosing a particular generator.